# How can I select parent id's that have two specific child id's from the "many" table of a one-to-many relationship?

Tags: mysql, sql, one-to-many

Let's say I have a table that lists various toys and the types of batteries they take:

```
toy_id   battery_id    battery_qty
     1            3              1
     2            2              4
     2            3              1
     3            1              1
```

I want to construct a query that will tell me which toys take *both* battery types 2 and 3 (but might take others as well). In the example above, that's toy_id 2.

How do I go about writing a query like that?

Here's what I have so far, but it seems messy:

```
SELECT t1.toy_id,
    t1.battery_id b1, t2.battery_id b2,
    t1.battery_qty qty1, t2.battery_qty qty2
FROM toys t1
LEFT JOIN toys t2
    ON t1.toy_id = t2.toy_id
WHERE t1.battery_id = 2
    AND t2.battery_id = 3
HAVING q1 > 0
    AND q2 > 0
ORDER BY toy_id ASC;
```

The results look correct, but I'm curious if I missed something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think join is not really need here. You only need to count the number of instances of the record and which is equal to the number of conditions you have searched.

```
SELECT  toy_ID
FROM    toys
WHERE   battery_ID IN (2,3)
GROUP BY toy_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97945/1)

but if unique constraint was not define on battery_id for each toy_id, `DISTINCT` is need on the `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT  toy_ID
FROM    toys
WHERE   battery_ID IN (2,3)
GROUP BY toy_ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT battery_ID) = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97945/2)

Comment: There is a unique index on the table that specifies toy_id and battery_id; so there won't be any duplicate battery_id rows for a given toy_id.

Comment: you just need `HAVING COUNT(*) = 2` `:D`

Comment: I think this query is producing too few results. I think it is because it is requiring *only* the two specified battery types, whereas I'd like my query to find toys that take the two battery types, but could optionally have additional types. I'll edit my question to mention this.

Comment: well, it's your call. if you want to search for atleast three types, do you need to add extra join again? Based on your comment below, you have 900 result, an those were really exact result? My query is wrong then.

Comment: I know what you're thinking, "A toy that takes *three* types of batteries? What in the world?" I modified the question to simplify what I am really doing and picked toys and batteries as the example. :)

Comment: I added a row to the toys table which allows toy_id 2 to take battery_id 4, and your query still works correctly. Further investigation ensues...

Comment: It came down to a typo. The battery_id in my live query was off by one in trying the different queries. Your query is accurate. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `full` join without `qty` (assuming battery_qty is always > 0 in your table) as:

```
  SELECT distinct t1.toy_id
  FROM toys t1
  JOIN toys t2
  ON t1.toy_id = t2.toy_id
  WHERE t1.battery_id = 2
    AND t2.battery_id = 3
  ORDER BY toy_id ASC;
```

Comment: This produces the same result, so looks good so far. None of the entries in this table will have a 0 qty, so eliminating the `HAVING` works; I had it as a precaution.

Comment: @JYelton Is something still missing?

Comment: I'm not sure. My query as well as yours produces 900 results in my live table. @Kuya's produces only 55. However in a small table that matches my example, both queries produce the correct result (toy_id 2).

Comment: @JYelton I used `distinct` as `SELECT distinct t1.toy_id` and only selecting `t1.toy_id`. Are you runnign the same exact query as posted in my answer?

Comment: Thanks for the help, ultimately I prefer the query without doing a join.